# How do I calculate a "rolling" statistic on this pandas table, but with the time-window centered on the datapoint?

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have the following pandas table:

```
import pandas as pd
import math
l = [['f8196bb6d34a9f44e950e30f15e1a2ab_6862', 1605148870, 51.98157826, 5.85744811], ['f8196bb6d34a9f44e950e30f15e1a2ab_6862', 1605141900, 51.98157842, 5.85744476], ['f8196bb6d34a9f44e950e30f15e1a2ab_6862', 1605145244, 51.98157826, 5.85744811], ['f8196bb6d34a9f44e950e30f15e1a2ab_6862', 1605153343, 51.98157826, 5.85744811], ['f8196bb6d34a9f44e950e30f15e1a2ab_6862', 1605143645, 51.98157842, 5.85744476], ['f8196bb6d34a9f44e950e30f15e1a2ab_6862', 1605159323, 51.98157826, 5.85744811], ['f8196bb6d34a9f44e950e30f15e1a2ab_6862', 1605157740, 51.98157826, 5.85744811], ['f8196bb6d34a9f44e950e30f15e1a2ab_6862', 1605150342, 51.98157826, 5.85744811]]
d = pd.DataFrame.from_records(l, columns=['device_zip', 'ts', 'lat', 'lon'])
d.sort_values(by=['ts'], inplace=True)
d['t'] = pd.to_datetime(d['ts'].astype(int), unit='s')
d['dummy'] = d.t.dt.hour
```

How do I calculate a new column where for every row, I count the number of rows with the dummy value > 40 in the following interval {1 minute before row's timestamp, 1 minute after row's timestamp} ? I've played around with the `rolling` function which can take a timewindow parameter, but I don't think it's possible to center the timewindow on each row.

I've been able to do what I want with an ugly loop construct, but it's quite slow. There must be a faster and more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Are you able to include a sample of your expected output please?

Comment: It's correct that centered windows are not supported for datetime windows but you can first add 1 min to `t` and then use a regular 2 min window like `d.set_index(d.t + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(minutes=1)).rolling("1T").dummy.sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed centered rolling with datetime does not seem possible. One work around is to do two `rolling` with half of the window you want and the second rolling being on the reverse data with `[::-1]`, then substract the value of the row as it has been counted twice. With the provided data, it is hard to implement your needs, so here are random data:

```
# random data
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2)
nb_rows = 20
d = pd.DataFrame(
    {'t':np.sort(
            np.random.choice(
                pd.date_range('2020-01-22 12:00:00',periods=nb_rows*10, freq='1s'), 
                size=nb_rows, replace=False)),   
     'dummy':40+np.random.choice([1,-1], size=nb_rows)})
```

Now you want to create a column that meets your criteria to use the `sum`, define the semi window and do both rolling:

```
d['dummy_count'] = d['dummy']>40
semi_win = '1T' # one minute for a 2 min window centered
d['roll_2T'] = (
    d.rolling(window=semi_win, min_periods=1, on='t')['dummy_count'].sum() 
    + d[::-1].rolling(window=semi_win, min_periods=1, on='t')['dummy_count'].sum()
    - d['dummy_count']
)

print(d)
                     t  dummy  dummy_count  roll_2T
0  2020-01-22 12:00:02     39        False      3.0 # value is 41 for 3 times up to 12:01:02
1  2020-01-22 12:00:03     39        False      3.0
2  2020-01-22 12:00:10     39        False      3.0
3  2020-01-22 12:00:12     39        False      3.0
4  2020-01-22 12:00:13     39        False      3.0
5  2020-01-22 12:00:14     41         True      3.0 
6  2020-01-22 12:00:29     39        False      3.0
7  2020-01-22 12:00:35     39        False      4.0
8  2020-01-22 12:00:44     41         True      4.0
9  2020-01-22 12:00:54     41         True      5.0 
10 2020-01-22 12:01:25     39        False      4.0 # 4 times 41 between 12:00:25 and 12:02:25
11 2020-01-22 12:01:32     41         True      4.0
12 2020-01-22 12:01:52     41         True      3.0
13 2020-01-22 12:01:53     39        False      3.0
14 2020-01-22 12:01:55     39        False      3.0
15 2020-01-22 12:02:06     39        False      3.0
16 2020-01-22 12:02:54     41         True      2.0
17 2020-01-22 12:03:02     39        False      2.0
18 2020-01-22 12:03:13     41         True      2.0
19 2020-01-22 12:03:19     39        False      2.0
```